# Acesso à checkbox de cada node de uma JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Como posso ter acesso à checkbox de cada node de uma `JTree`?

```
TreePath[] checkedPaths = checkTreeManager.getSelectionModel().getSelectionPaths();
```

O código anterior retorna-me todos os paths selecionados. Quando volto à minha `JTree` após perder o foco, gostava que essas paths estivessem selecionadas.

Tentei utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
jTree1.addSelectionPaths(checkedPaths);
```

A questão é que seleciona-me a linha dos nodes selecionados e não me faz check na checkbox associada como gostaria.

Alguém sabe como poderei resolver isto?

Comment: No segundo comando, ao adicionar as seleções, o objeto checkedPaths é o mesmo do primeiro comando?

Comment: Sim, é o mesmo!

Comment: Bom, você precisa selecionar do SelectionModel e não direto na jTree1. Assim: `checkTreeManager.getSelectionModel().addSelectionPaths(checkedPaths);`

Comment: E coloco esse comando após a jtree voltar a ser alimentada?

Comment: Esse comando você substitui pelo seu segundo comando na pergunta...

Comment: Se colocar como me disse, não seleciona como quero, talvez por erro meu aqui no código, no entanto se fizer: 'checkTreeManager.getSelectionModel().addSelectionPath(jTree1.getPathForRow(4));' seleciona certinho como quero, por isso vou guardar os índices dos paths selecionados e depois faço isso :D

Comment: @Earendul já consegui pôr a selecionar mas estou com problemas para selecionar os child nodes. Ex: root->A->A1, se o path for esse e eu selecionar o A1, ele não fica selecionado :s

Comment: Se o A só tiver esse filho, então ele vai ficar selecionado o A. Mas se o A não tiver irmãos, ele vai selecionar só o root. Ou seja, quando todos os filhos de um nó estiverem selecionados, ele retorna apenas o pai deles. Por exemplo, se ele retornar o A como último nó selecionado, significa que todos os filhos do A estão também selecionados.

Comment: Certo e no modo de seleção isso acontece, a questão é que eu tenho: Root->A->A1, A2 (onde A1 e A2 são filhos do A) se a minha seleção for o A1, ele não me seleciona esse path. Acho que sei onde tá o meu problema é que eu  tou a percorrer a jtree desta forma: for(int i = 0; i<jtree.getRowCount();i++) e supostamente esse rowCount creio que não conta o A1 e o A2, só conta Root-> A , B , C